# Interface Misunderstanding

Tags: c#, interface, parameters

I'm trying to increase my productivity and extensibility with Interfaces.  They are quite powerful, but I've hit a snag in either my understanding or implementation.

Hypothetically, if I have a *User Interface* that I have no control over; but I'm writing a *Class Library* that will perform a series of logic.  My original thought was something like this:

```
public interface ISiteForm
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     // Also any other User Interface Form Fields.
}
```

Which would be laid out like this, so it could be implemented and referenced by the *User Interface*.

```
public class SiteForm : ISiteForm
{
    public SiteForm()
    {
        FormPass();
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
         get { return lastName; }
         set { lastName = value; }
    }

    private string lastName,
    private string firstName,

    public void FormPass(string _lastName, string _firstName)
    {
        // Implementation to assign a value from User Interface into the interface.

        lastName = _lastName;
        firstName = _firstName;
    }
}
```

My thought was when the *Class Library* was referenced, they would pass those parameters to the method when it was called.  Then by nature when the class was created; it would assign those variables to the interface.

So then if I had any other portion of the project that required those same variables; I could simply call the interface and adjust the setter value.

My concerns are:

- Interfaces by nature don't expect logic
- They are usually Polymorphic, which would lose that specific implementation.

Is that the wrong approach for passing parameters through an interface so those same variables can be used elsewhere?

Comment: Interface are not used to share values between different classes. You inherit them and implement them.

Comment: Are you confusing an interface as in a code contract with a user interface i.e. a UI?

Comment: @BenRobinson I just might be.

Comment: If i didn't know any better, I'd think you were trying to impliment some form of the javascript-style prototyping.

Comment: That is what I thought.  But I think I saw something on a post that used a decoupled approach with interfaces like that. So in turn it confused me, which I confused myself then. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I am using `interface` to extend new class (base class + some interfaces), or as a unified form to "identify" things and perform action accordingly: `if(obj is IMyInterface1) (obj as IMyInterface1).Property = val; if(obj is IMyInterface2) (obj as IMyInterface2).DoSmth(val1, val2);`. To provide shared functionality you have to use implemented class.

Comment: @Sinatr could you provide an answer with more detail to with that implementation?

Comment: @Greg you have to supply to others not interfaces, but already made classes, which will use other interfaces (also supplied by you) already. So basically others have option either to use ur classes as base or to use your classes with their classes (containing your interfaces implementaions). I did that when providing configuration to different devices, someone else can use my configuration class as a base, add my interfaces (to extend functionaly in predefined way) and all the rest (all controlling logic) will detect and perform appropriately.

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for the post.  Between the examples in Fowlers book and trying to siph through the best approach I obviously confused myself and lost site of interfaces.  I usually don't use them, as I haven't had a need to yet.  But I'm trying to get those "good practices and habits" so I thought it time.  Thank you for clarifying.  Thats why I love the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that the wrong approach for passing parameters through an interface
>   so those same variables can be used elsewhere?

Be careful not to confuse object instances with type declarations.  A local variable of type `ISiteForm` is accessible in the block which it is declared.  For example,

```
public void M()
{
    ISiteForm s = new SiteForm();
}
```

If I declared `s` as a `SiteForm` the change does not make the object instance `s` any more accessible to other parts of the program.

An interface does allow us to treat an object uniformly regardless of the underlying type of the object.

E.G.

```
public void M(ISiteForm s)
{
    var propertyName = s.FirstName;
}
```

Here, I don't know or care if `s` is a type of `SiteForm` or some other type that happens to implement `ISiteForm`.  The behavior is polymorphic.

> **Which would be laid out like this, so it could be implemented and referenced by the User 
>   Interface.**

To that point, Interfaces can be used to decouple layers in an n-tier architecture.  For example, you may create an Interfaces.dll.  This DLL can house `ISiteForm`.  The User interface and Business Logic can  both reference this shared DLL. This design allows loose coupling by allowing otherwise unrelated objects to be passed between layers and helps to avoid [circular references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference).

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign anything to the interface, it's an implementation contract. The implementing class contains all the logic.

If you wanted to use the same interface and variables you might want to look at something like Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces aren't for anything but polymorphism.  You should not put any logic in them at all.

Comment: That was my original thought.  But the example I saw just confused me- and come up with the above outlandish question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions, I revisited the solution.  This is how I ended up handling it, I used *Dependency Injection: Interface Injection* approach.  This methodology provided the decoupled approach I required; while still maintaining the goal of functionality.

I created the following:

```
public interface ISiteForm
{
     string GetSiteValues(string FirstName, string LastName);
}
```

This particular interface will act as our *Dependency* or `IDependency`.  Then I created the following `Class`.

```
public class SiteForm : ISiteForm
{
    // Leave for now.
}
```

So now at this point we've preconfigured our `Interface` and `Class`.  This will act as a our *Dependency*.

Now to setup our injector.

```
public interface ISiteFormInjector
{
    void InjectSiteForm(ISiteForm siteDetails);
}
```

Our injector will be our *Dependent* or in our case `IDependent`.  Now we need to update our code so the data injection is physically implemented.

```
public class SiteContent : ISiteFormInjector
{
    // Call our Dependency.
    ISiteForm _siteDetails;

    public void InjectSiteForm(ISiteForm siteDetails)
    {
         _siteDetails = siteDetails;
    }

    // Properties to Associate our Value.
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string GetSiteValues()
    {
        return _siteDetails.GetSiteValues(FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

And now the values can be injected; obviously with some refactoring it will be able to have the value injected then will pass those variables to other aspects of the application. It follows this form of layout:

[image: UML For Interface Injection]